# .NET Core: How to get a `Controller` instance (or just it's full name) from ViewLocationExpanderContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC5, I had my own `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine` and had the following:

```
string controllerAssemblyName = controllerContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.FullName;
```

I used that for dynamically adding view locations.

Anyway, I am migrating to .NET Core and writing my own `IViewLocationExpander` and need to determine the controller type there to do the same thing. The method signature is as follows:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
```

All I have is an instance of `ViewLocationExpanderContext`, which only provides `ControllerName` and `AreaName` properties, but no actual instance of a Controller. Is there a way to get an instance or at least full type name of the controller using those 2 properties?

I also tried the following:

```
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.ActionContext);`
```

That gives me an instance of `ControllerContext`, but unlike MVC5, it doesn't have a `Controller` property on it.

Comment: Check the `ActionContext`. That should provide the necessary details. Check if it is one of its derived types and see if you can't get details about the controller from it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewlocationexpandercontext?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: My money is on the descriptor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor.controllertypeinfo?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Controllers_ControllerActionDescriptor_ControllerTypeInfo

Comment: Anyone here know how to get the Instance which I can cast to a specific controller type? Versus just the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the `ActionContext` to access the desired information.

Should be able to drill down into the context to get the action controller type info and assembly full name

```
public virtual IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations) {

    var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
    if(controllerActionDescriptor != null) {
        var controllerTypeInfo = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo;            
        //From the type info you should be able to get the assembly
        var controllerAssemblyName = controllerTypeInfo.AsType().Assembly.FullName.ToString();
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I was working on a different solution when I saw your answer.. and I've now combined them both into my final solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nkosi. I have used his answer and my solution is as follows. I am not sure if the `CreateControllerFactory()` part is good, but it's my fallback in case `controllerActionDescriptor` is NULL:

```
string controllerAssemblyName = null;

var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
{
    var controllerTypeInfo = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo;
    controllerAssemblyName = controllerTypeInfo.AsType().Assembly.FullName;
}
else
{
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.ActionContext);
    var factory = CreateControllerFactory();
    var controller = factory.CreateController(controllerContext);
    controllerAssemblyName = controller.GetType().Assembly.FullName;
}


private static DefaultControllerFactory CreateControllerFactory()
{
    var propertyActivators = new IControllerPropertyActivator[]
    {
        new DefaultControllerPropertyActivator(),
    };

    return new DefaultControllerFactory(
        new DefaultControllerActivator(new TypeActivatorCache()), 
        propertyActivators);
}
```