# Get Controller from ControllerContext Asp Core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Im upgrading my .NET Framework project to .NET Core. I have a line of code in a BaseModel class `ControllerContext.Controller as Controllers.BaseController;`

ControllerContext in .NET Core doesnt seem to have `.Controller` anymore. Is there anyway to access this in Core?

Comment: You can get the controller instance in an action filter, but you can't get it outside of that.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502441/net-core-how-to-get-a-controller-instance-or-just-its-full-name-from-view).